# Size of an object in raster image based on DPI resolution and number of pixels

Tags: raster, area, resolution, terrset

I'm trying to estimate the size of an object in a raster image, with known DPI resolution.

To evaluate the validity of this method, I do as follows:

1) I'm drawing a 0,02 in × 0,02 in black square in Scribus and export the image to TIFF with 2400 DPI resolution

2) I'm importing the image into Idrisi Selva with GEOTIFF/TIFF import method

3) I'm doing a RECLASS operation to binarize the image, so that square pixels are "1"s, and the background is "0"s

4) I'm running AREA database query operation to estimate the size of the square in "cells". The result is: 1722.

5) Because there are 2400 pixels in one inch, one pixel has 1/2400 inches in length, and thus (1/2400)² area in in²

6) Thus the estimated size of the square is ~0,0012 whereas the real size is 0,0004.

Why the difference? The results are the same when exporting with 1200 DPI, so it doesn't seem to be a matter of accuracy.

Comment: How does Idrisi Selva decide the geographic coordinates for your GeoTIFF? The file should have some coordinate reference system, and that defines the pixel size rather than the DPI value. I suspect it may use some default lat-long coordinates and so your area is in square degrees. Your assumption that the pixels are 1/2400" square is probably wrong. Can you get Idrisi to dump more info about the file after loading it?

Comment: Reference system is specified as "plane". There are no any "geo" metadata in this file as it was created in no GIS related software. I am not sure how IDRISI deals with such TIFFs.